# How to get apnsToken even FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled is set to YES in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

##### Why do I need it?

- I am using firebase for push notification so I needed `fcmToken` is stored into my DB for current logic.
- Then I am integrating a third-party push notifications service and they needed `apnsToken`

##### What I need

How to get `apnsToken` and `fcmToken` as the same time?

##### Issue

When I turn `ON` `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` then `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` never gets called. So I could not get apns Token. What should I do?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {}
```

I can only get fcmToken from this function

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {}
```

Please help!